# Google App Engine: Is it safe to reveal a user's user_id publicly

Tags: security, google-app-engine

Is there any personal identifying information linked to this number?

Are user_id's specific to my app or does a user have the same user_id across all app engine apps?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but if it _weren't_ safe, I doubt Google would make it visible to GAE developers.

Answer (score 1):

`user_id` is basically same across all GAE apps, and it might be possible to get other user info using `user = User(_user_id = 'user_id')`, so I'd recommend to avoid using user id's in URLs and other client-visible information.

Comment: Creating a user as described will not expose any user information. The User class is merely a data holder. You can see the source code of it at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/users.py

Comment: I guess if you found another GAE app that used the user_id in a url to a public profile that contained an email address or real name this would be a problem.

Comment: @SebastianKreft actually it requires a few more steps, like putting the `User` into the database and reading it back. I have used this approach to get an `user_id` when I have only e-mail, but it might as well work in the other direction, people mentioned it working in 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3097502/1329296

Comment: @lenik The `User` class in the `users` module is only a data holder, no lookup is done. What you are now describing requires that you have seen the user before and stored its data.